# Import a package defined by a variable

Tags: python

I want to do some package import timing tests. For this, I want to define a list of packages:

```
packages = [ 'random', 'dateutils', ... ]

for package in packages:
    import package
```

This is of course not working because `import` tries to import package "package". How can I tell `import` to import the package pointed to by the variable "package"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I import a package using __import__() when the package name is only known at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057843/how-can-i-import-a-package-using-import-when-the-package-name-is-only-know)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for package in packages:
    package = __import__(package)
```

Note that if you are importing a module from a package, such as `A.B`,

`__import__('A.B')` returns package `A`, but `__import__('A.B', fromlist = [True])` returns module `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the description of `"__import__"` method in the manual may be helpful for you.