# importlib.import_module adding * to globals?

Tags: python

Trying to dynamically add settings attributes to `globals()` according to some dynamic environment variables.

```
import os
from importlib import import_module


# To support environment variables as the means of specifying
# the target environment as an alternative to using the --settings flag
# where MY_ENV is 'local', 'development', 'staging', 'production'
if os.environ.get('MY_ENV'):
    env = os.environ.get('MY_ENV')
    import_module('my.settings.%s' % env, '*')
```

Its understood that `import_module` needs to be assigned to a variable:

```
foo = import_module('path.to.package', 'bar')
```

and that:

```
globals()[foo] = foo
```

can add this to the `global` scope.

However, what is to be done with the wildcard `*`?

```
globals()[*] = import_module('path.to.package', '*')
```

Obviously, the above causes a syntax error.

Comment: Seems similar for sure.

Comment: I don't think the second argument to `import_module` means what you think it means. It's the package relative imports should be relative to; none of your examples is a relative import.

Comment: I see.  I think I were more trying to use string interpolation to dynamically alter the import path.

Comment: This question is answered here:

[Python: How to import all methods and attributes from a module dynamically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221358/python-how-to-import-all-methods-and-attributes-from-a-module-dynamically

Comment: Hmmm, trying to answer this or mark as a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

to do what you want, you need to use "__import__()" and not import_module()

I think this answer can help you

[How can I import a package using __import__() when the package name is only known at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057843/how-can-i-import-a-package-using-import-when-the-package-name-is-only-know)